# Test failing for duplicate users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am following a tutorial and so far my tests have been successful until I wrote the last test for uniqueness of email addresses

**test/models/user_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

.
.   
.


  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end
```

The model itself includes the following validations.

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase! }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
                     has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

with the last test i get a boolean error

```
" test_email_addresses_should_be_unique#UserTest (0.87s)
        Expected true to be nil or false"
```

I set the uniqueness validation to omit case sensitivity.  Therefore, shouldn't the duplicate  user  be  invalidated?

the full  test:
**test/models/user_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.create(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

   test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                         first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
  end
     test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                           foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end

  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
     duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save!
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end
```

Comment: What is `@user`? Is is a user save into the database? Did you double check that the user exists?

Comment: Just updated. Yes the user is saved  in the database.

Comment: The uniqueness validation only considers other users when they have already been saved to the database. Using `@user = User.create(...)` in your `setup` should make your test green. Let me know if it helped :)

Comment: i  changed the  variable to create, but the test is still failing. The error however  is different this time "test_should_be_valid#UserTest (1.06s)
        Expected false to be truthy"

Comment: Can you please change `@user.save` to `@user.save!`

Comment: Update: I have deleted all users that were previously in the database. I updated the method to @user.save!  and the error has changed to  
    `test_email_addresses_should_be_unique#UserTest (0.88s)
    NoMethodError: undefined method "upcase" for nil:NilClass` which is still confusing?

Comment: I what line does that error occur? In this one `duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase`? Than `@user.email` is `nil`... Do you use the same `@user` in other tests before? for example to test the validation for presence of email?

Comment: I updated with the full test page. Yes the user was used in other tests but i did not `user.save!` until i wrote the `duplicate_user` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out your code on my machine and it seems the problem is in the `before_save` callback.

The bang version `downcase!` modifies the string itself and if there were any changes made (i.e., any characters downcased) returns the result, otherwise returns `nil`.

While `downcase` returns a copy of the string with all characters in lowercase. So you can use one of the following approaches: `before_save { self.email = email.downcase }` or `before_save { email.downcase! }`.